# DataTable - Selection RadioButton Primefaces 5 not work?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Hi community I have a query with radio button selection in datatable of primefaces 5, when I click to register and invoke the event to edit, not capturing the registry value returns me null object.

My code xhtml:

```
<p:dataTable id="tblProductos" var="producto"
    value="#{cBusquedaProducto.lazyDataProductos}"
    rowIndexVar="rowIndex" lazy="true" rows="10"
    paginator="true" paginatorPosition="top"
    rowKey="#{producto.icodProducto}"
    selectionMode="single"
    selection="#{cBusquedaProducto.producto}"
    emptyMessage="#{msg['tabla.noExistenRegistros']}"           
    paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
    currentPageReportTemplate="Registros: {totalRecords} - [ {currentPage} de {totalPages} ]"
    rowsPerPageTemplate="10,20,30,40,50,200">

    <p:column selectionMode="single" />

    <p:column style="text-align: center;">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="#{msg['form.item']}" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{rowIndex + 1}" />
    </p:column> 
    <p:column style="text-align: center;">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="#{msg['form.codigo']}" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{producto.icodProducto}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column style="text-align: center;">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="#{msg['form.descripcion']}" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{producto.vdesProducto}" />
    </p:column>
    .......
</p:dataTable>
```

Controller:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "cBusquedaProducto")
@ViewScoped
public class CBusquedaProducto extends BaseController {

    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{iProductoService}")
    private IProductoService iProductoService;

    private LazyDataModel<ProductoBean> lazyDataProductos;

    @PostConstruct
    @Override
    public void inicializarObjetos() {
        try {
            /* Cargamos las listas */
            Map<String, Serializable> filters = new HashMap<String, Serializable>();
            filters.put("param.icodEmpresa", Constantes.ONE_INT);
            this.lazyDataProductos = new ProductoLazyDataModel(iProductoService, filters);
            this.opcProducto = Constantes.ONE_SHORT;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error(getGenerarError(
                    Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName(),
                    Constantes.NIVEL_APP_CONSTROLLER,
                    this.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage()));
        }
    }

    ... get and set

}
```

LazyDataModel:

```
public class ProductoLazyDataModel extends LazyDataModel<ProductoBean> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    private List<ProductoBean> datasource;
    Map<String, Serializable> extFilters = new HashMap<String, Serializable>();
    private int pageSize;
    private int rowIndex;
    private int rowCount;
    private IProductoService iProductoService;

    /**
     * @param iProductoService - El servicio para obtener datos desde base de datos.
     * @param extFilters - Los filtros a aplicar a las columnas, acepta nulo.
     */
    public ProductoLazyDataModel(IProductoService iProductoService,
            Map<String, Serializable> extFilters) {
        this.iProductoService = iProductoService;
        this.extFilters = extFilters;
    }

    @Override
    public List<ProductoBean> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField,
            SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, Object> filters) {
        try {
            SortCriteria sort = new SortCriteria();
            if (sortField == null) {
                sort.add("icodProducto", false);
            } else {
                if (sortOrder == SortOrder.ASCENDING) {
                    sort.add(sortField, true);
                } else {
                    sort.add(sortField, false);
                }
            }
            WrappedData<ProductoBean> wd = iProductoService.obtenerProductos(filters,
                                                            extFilters, sort, first, pageSize);
            datasource = wd.getData();
            setRowCount(wd.getRowCount().intValue());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.toString());
        }
        return datasource;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isRowAvailable() {
        if (datasource == null)
            return false;
        int index = rowIndex % pageSize;
        return index >= 0 && index < datasource.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getRowKey(ProductoBean gr) {
        return gr.getIcodProducto();
    }

    @Override
    public ProductoBean getRowData() {
        if (datasource == null)
            return null;
        int index = rowIndex % pageSize;
        if (index > datasource.size()) {
            return null;
        }
        return datasource.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public ProductoBean getRowData(String rowKey) {
        if (datasource == null)
            return null;
        for (ProductoBean gr : datasource) {
            String cod = String.valueOf(gr.getIcodProducto());
            if (cod.equals(rowKey)) {
                return gr;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void setPageSize(int pageSize) {
        this.pageSize = pageSize;
    }

    @Override
    public int getPageSize() {
        return pageSize;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowIndex() {
        return this.rowIndex;
    }

    @Override
    public void setRowIndex(int rowIndex) {
        this.rowIndex = rowIndex;
    }

    @Override
    public void setRowCount(int rowCount) {
        this.rowCount = rowCount;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return this.rowCount;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public void setWrappedData(Object list) {
        this.datasource = (List<ProductoBean>) list;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getWrappedData() {
        return datasource;
    }
}
```

Hope you can help me, because I find the reason, I've tried with chekbox and with that if it works but with radiobutton not working ....

Comment: What "registry values"? I don't see any component in your view that performs a row edit, not even an ajax tag. Your question is incomplete and unclear

Comment: What happens is that null is capturing well, that's the problem.